# How to make a Cassandra partition feel like a wide-row in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Cassandra exposes its partitions as multiples rows, however internally that are stored as wide-rows and that is the way I would like to work on my data with Spark.

To be more specific I will, one way or another get a RDD of Cassandra partitions, or a dataframe of these.

Then I would like to do a `map` operation, and in the closure, I would like to express something like this:

```
row['parameter1']['value'] / len(row['parameter2']['vector_value'])
```

pseudo code just to give an idea, a simple division and taking the lenght of a vector.

My table would be

```
create table(
    dataset_name text,
    parameter     text,
    value         real,
    vector_value  list<real>,
    primary key(dataset_name, parameter));
```

How can I do that efficiencly? Using with PySpark.

I think I need something like [Pandas `set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Logically, RDD groupBy seems to me to be what you want to do.
RDD groupBy is said to be bad for large grouping, but here we are grouping on a cassandra partition, so it is supposed to be kept in a spark partition, and it is supposed to be locally as all rows of one partition would be on the same node.

I'm more using Scala with Spark than Python, so let's try. But I did not tested it.
I would suggest

rdd =sc.cassandraTable('keyspace','table').map(lambda x: ( (x.dataset_name, (x.parameter , value, vector_value) )) // create the key to group on

rdd2 = sorted ( rdd.groupByKey() ) // GroupByKey returns (key, Iterator), hence sorted to get a list

Look groupBy / groupByKey functions

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD

You will get one row per partition, and inside each partition, a list of clustering rows. so you should be able to access with [0] for the first occurence so 'parameter1', then [1] for 'parameter2'

EDIT: A colleague told me spark-cassandra-connector provides RDD methods to make what you want, ie preserving clustering column grouping and ordering. They are called spanBy / spanByKey : https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#grouping-rows-by-partition-key